# Python-like List-functionality in Java

Tags: java, arrays, list

I want to store several items, each with a specific set of attributes (Strings as well as Numbers), using Java. 
In Python, I would do this in a list:
`[item1 [attribute1, attribute2, attribute3 ...], item2 [attribute1, attribute2,..]].`

The Lists, maps, Dictionaries in Java seem to be unuseful, as you can only store "at most one value", Arrays seem to be the most promising, but they con only contain values of one type - yet I need to store both Strings and Numbers. 
Is it possible to store data in Java in a similar way like in Python?

Comment: you could just store all strings and convert to int using Integer.parseInt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll just need to define your own object and store a list of that type:

```
public class MyObject {
    String att1;
    int att2;
    //...etc
    public MyObject(String _att1, int _att2) {
        att1 = _att1;
        att2 = _att2;
        //...etc
    }

}
```

Then create a list out of your object:

```
List<MyOjbect> MyList = new ArrayList<MyObject>();
MyObject obj = new MyObject("att1", 2);
MyList.add(obj);
```

Not nearly as succinct as Python, but you can get the same results with a little extra code.

Comment: I tried several things, and in the end, i used your suggestion; i had to modify it here and there, so it took a while until i had it figured out, but it works :)